# Remove Border from Linklabel C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `LinkLabel`, by setting `BorderStyle=none` there is a thin border around it when I run the Form.
I want to remove this thin border from the linklabel. How can I achieve this?

The Code Of My Linklabel Is

```
            linkLabel1.AccessibleRole = System.Windows.Forms.AccessibleRole.Alert;
            linkLabel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            linkLabel1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tw Cen MT Condensed", 13F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            linkLabel1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HotTrack;
            linkLabel1.LinkBehavior = System.Windows.Forms.LinkBehavior.NeverUnderline;
            linkLabel1.LinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue;
            linkLabel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(129, 330);
            linkLabel1.Name = "linkLabel1";
            linkLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(68, 21);
            linkLabel1.TabIndex = 7;
            linkLabel1.TabStop = true;
            linkLabel1.Text = "Contact Us";
            linkLabel1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
            linkLabel1.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(this.linkLabel1_LinkClicked);
```

Linklabel Code Output Screenshot
http://tinypic.com/r/20rk09v/6
Linklabel Code Design View Scrrenshot
http://tinypic.com/r/4kzj9y/6

Comment: please show me the code showing the LinkLabel

Comment: Probably look at the properties; bordercolor, borderwidth (or bordersize) things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
this.label.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
```

Comment: I have Done The Same But Not Achieved This See The Question Again I Have Uploaded The Detailed Code Of Linked Label

Answer (score 8):

If you already Set the `BorderStyle` property to `none`, I guess you are talking about the link underline as the border. If yes, you can change that behavior in the properties. There is a property called `LinkBehaviour` and you can select the Value to `NeverUnderLine` to avoid the underline.

[image]

Comment: I have Done The Same But Not Achieved This See The Question Again I Have Uploaded The Detailed Code Of Linked Label

Comment: can you put a screen shot of how the link looks like ?